# How can I calculate the jacobian matrix for eit inverse problem?

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

I am currently working in a inverse problem,  in matlab, I observed voltage data from electrode and I discretized my model using the FEM. I applied cosine current and I solved the voltage values. This is forward problem. 
My problem is inverse problem which is  delta(conductivity)=S* delta(voltage)

The problem is in the building of the jacobian Matrix, I am not sure how I should start to build it; Is there any method that can achieve what I want? I have searched some methods for calculation but ı am wrong because my solution is wrong.  I am unsure on how I should start creating it.

Thank you very much

Comment: I am studying in Electrical impedance tomography.

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do? Calculate the Jacobian of a given function? If yes, what is this function?

Comment: Actually, my problem is Sij(k)=(∫∇φ(i)*∇φ(j)*ds)     φ(i)=a(i)+b(i)x+c(i)y  and  φ(j)=a(j)+b(j)x+c(j)y    k is number of element in all mesh.    i=1,2,3 and j=1,2,3 because my element is triangle which has three node . Thank you

Comment: I solve before questions but I have a new question J=T[-(dS^(-1) (σ))/dσ* I] . How can I solve this equation? This S matrix is sparse matrix and conductivity(σ) is scalar . So how can I calculate the derivative according to scalar number ?